# C programming recursion

Tags: c, visual-studio, recursion

I was into C today and I bumped into this example of using recursive calls and I don't understand how it works. Can someone explain?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define SIZE 10 

int sample(const int b[], int p); //function prototype

void main(void){
    int x; 

    int a[SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    x = sample(a, SIZE); //call

    printf("Result is X: %d\n", x);
}

int sample(const int b[], int p){
    if (p == 1){
        return b[0];
    }
    else{
        return b[p - 1] + sample(b, p - 1); //recursive calls until p is 1
    }
}
```

My question is: Why the output is 55? Does x save the previous value and then add next from next call of the sample? Why the value of x is not just b[0] which is 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might help is to write out a table of the value of `p` at the first call of `sample`:

```
p          b[p - 1]
--------   --------
SIZE       10
```

Since `p` is not `1`, the function `sample` returns the calculation:

```
b[SIZE - 1] + sample(b, SIZE - 1)
```

Or:

```
10 + sample(b, SIZE - 1)
```

To calculate `sample(b, SIZE - 1)`, we write out the next value in the table:

```
p          b[p - 1]
--------   --------
SIZE - 1   9
```

Again, `p` is not `1`, so we ultimately return the following value:

```
(10 + (9 + sample (b, (SIZE - 1) - 1)))
```

If you repeat these steps, you can see how this eventually terminates, because we get to a state where `p` is `1`:

```
(10 + (9 + (8 + ... + (1)))
```

This results in the answer `55`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 55 as that's the sum of all 10 terms.
What it's doing is summing the last term with the sum of the others. When presented with the first term it returns that, ending recursion and popping the whole stack.

Answer (score 1):

It happen because when you execute the above code then a memory stack of recursive function call outputs is formed till there is a controlling condition like in this case we have

```
 if (p == 1){
        return b[0];
    }
```

so the values you get at every level of recursion are as follows 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Adding all of them you get 55.

The value of x is not just 1 because the return value of each recursive function calls for decremented values of P is added to calculate the return value of previous call at each call till it reaches 1 (the condition in the parent call).
 ie `return b[p - 1] + sample(b, p - 1);`

For brief explanation refer : http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-recursion